# Adding parameters for a program at launch

Tags: c++, parameters

I'm currently trying to make a small application that performs different duties. Right now I have a console app pop up and ask what I want to do, but sometimes I would rather just launch it with something like MyApp.exe -printdocuments or some such thing.

Are there any tutorials out there that can show me a simple example of this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++, your `main()` function can have `argc` and `argv` parameters, which contain the arguments passed on the command line. The `argc` is the count of arguments (including the executable name itself), and `argv` is an array of pointers to null-terminated strings of length `argc`.

For example, this program prints its arguments:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("argv[%d]: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any C or C++ tutorial will probably have more information on this.

Answer (score 5):

You can use boost::program_options to do this, If you don't want to use boost library, you must parse main function arguments by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

`getopt` is a posix function (implementations for windows exist) that can help you parse your arguments:

```
#include <unistd.h> // getopt

// call with my_tool [-n] [-t <value>]
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int opt;
    int nsecs;
    bool n_given = false, t_given = false;
    // a colon says the preceding option takes an argument
    while ((opt = ::getopt(argc, argv, "nt:")) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
        case 'n':
            n_given = true;
            break;
        case 't':
            nsecs = boost::lexical_cast<int>(optarg);
            t_given = true;
            break;
        default: /* '?' */
            std::cerr << "Usage: "
                      << argv[0] << " [-t <value>] [-n]\n";
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would do well to use a library for this. Here are a few links that might get you started on command line arguments with c++.

1. [gperf](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-gperf.html)

Answer (score 0):

your entry point method i.e. in C++ your main method needs to look like

```
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] );
```

you can read this [article](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson14.html) and accomplish what you are trying to do